# How to compute variance of sample average with sympy?

Tags: python, statistics, sympy, sample, variance

I want to compute the expected mean values of several symbolic expressions with Sympy - an easy example would be the expected mean value of a sample with size m, where each sample point is taken from a normal distribution with mean mu and std sigma. m, mu and sigma are symbols.

I tried `sample_avg = 1/m*summation(Normal('xi',mu,sigma),(i,0,m-1))`, but this yields only xi, meaning that it just sums over identical xi. As expected, `Variance(sample_avg)` yields `Variance(xi)` instead of `sigma**2/m`

Which term belongs in the summation then? `Normal(Indexed("x",i),mu,sigma)` doesn't work either.

For Poisson distributions, there seems to be `PoissonProcess`, but I can't seem to make this work:

```
from sympy import summation, symbols
from sympy.stats import variance, E, PoissonProcess
m,i = symbols("m i", positive=True,indexed=True)
mu_x = symbols("mu_x", positive=True)
pp = PoissonProcess("pp", lamda=mu_x)
x_avg = 1/m * summation(pp(ii), (i,0,m-1))
print(E(x_avg))
```

this now complains that lamba must be > 0, but I already specified that mu_x is positive.